# Google Maps API dropdown list, zoom to marker

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps API v3, I have a simple map with a few markers. I also have a pull down list. I need the least amount of code to make this work. I would like to select a marker in the pull down list and have the marker selected pan to it. I have tried everything as well as look online and I find things close, but nothing is working so far, very frustrated so far. Pls Help! here is the snippet:

I need to figure out how to make this work

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet  -->    
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey&sensor=false">
    </script>
    <br>
    <script>
        var geocoder;
        var directionsService;
        var directionsDisplay;
        //Start of code (above is framework)  
      function initialize() {
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.682, -100.103);
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 5,
          center: myLatLng,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
        };
        //Map Framework above
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions); //Map Options

        //google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('SelectList'),
        //  'change', function() {}
        //var mypos = document.getElementById('SelectList').value;

        // Marker2 (Red - default marker color)
            var latLng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(43.239316, -96.259241);
            var contentString2 = '<div id="content">'+
            var infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString2
            });

            var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng2,
            icon: src='http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/red-circle.png',
            //new google.maps.Size(42,68)
            //size: (12, 10),
            //position: mypos,
            map: map,
            title: "marker ...)" //hover 
            });


            google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function() {
            infowindow2.open(map, marker2);

            });

            //moved 'SelectList' up toward top!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

        // End code for Marker 2
        // Start of Marker3 (Yellow - marker color)
            var latLng3 = new google.maps.LatLng(44.021778, -96.052417); 
            var contentString3 = '<div id="content">'+
            var infowindow3 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString3
            });

            var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng3,
            icon: src='http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/ylw-circle.png',
            map: map,
            title: "Marker ..."   
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker3, 'click', function() {
            infowindow3.open(map, marker3);
            });

        // End for Marker 3
        // Start of Marker4 (Green - marker color)
            var latLng4 = new google.maps.LatLng(43.881690, -95.922869); 
            var contentString4 = '<div id="content">'+
            var infowindow4 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString4
            });

            var marker4 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng4,
            icon: src='http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/grn-circle.png',
            map: map,
            title: "marker ..."   
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker4, 'click', function() {
            infowindow4.open(map, marker4);
            });

            var infowindow4 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString4
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker4, 'click', function() {
            infowindow4.open(map, marker4);
            });
            // End code for Marker 3

            });

</script> 
</head>
    <body onload="initialize()">
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width:80%; height:95%"></div>
        <br>
        <div style="position: absolute; right: 25px; top: 15px; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
        <h3><u>Marker List by area</u></h3>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div style="position: absolute; right: 25px; top: 165px; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;"> 
        <form>
           <fieldset>
              <legend><b>Region 1</b></legend>
              <p>
             <label><b>Marker List</b></label>
             <select id = "myList3">
               <option value = "9">Marker 1</option>
               <option value = "10">Marker 2</option>
               <option value = "11">Marker 3</option>
               <option value = "12">Marker 4</option>
             </select>
              </p>
           </fieldset>
        </form></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [v3 example with dropdown to select markers](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map15c.html)

Comment: @geocodezip - I realize this, however this doesn't solve my problems. If you view source, it doesn't follow exactly what I am doing. Please advise. I would like to know if I add something near the listener to link this or do I add something in the select tag (my options list). Not to mention if you copy this and paste in a editor it doesn't work...

Comment: It demonstrates the functionality you are looking for (without the zoom to marker, but that would be simple to add).  If it doesn't help you, ignore it.  II had hoped it would let you see what you needed to do.

Comment: It does everything I need, however I can't find the actual code to perform the pull down event to the marker. I don't need to zoom to as it centers it (which is fine) I just need to know what code and where do I put it for linking the pulldown and the markers. Need help!!??

Comment: The map needs to be like this http://www.warrenknjiru.webs.com/realestate.html but with a pulldown and not as links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the markers elsewhere and identifiy them when the dropdown changes. Hook your dropdown like this: onchange="dropdownChanged()"

Your code should look like this:

```
    <script >
        var geocoder;
        var directionsService;
        var directionsDisplay;
        var markers = [];
        var map;
        //Start of code (above is framework)  
        function initialize() {
            var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.682, -100.103);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 5,
                center: myLatLng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
            };
            //Map Framework above
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions); //Map Options

            //google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('SelectList'),
            //  'change', function() {}
            //var mypos = document.getElementById('SelectList').value;

            // Marker2 (Red - default marker color)
            var latLng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(43.239316, -96.259241);
            var contentString2 = '<div id="content">';
            var infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: contentString2
            });

            var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng2,
                icon: src = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/red-circle.png',
                //new google.maps.Size(42,68)
                //size: (12, 10),
                //position: mypos,
                map: map,
                title: "marker ...)" //hover 
            });

            markers[10] = marker2;

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function () {
                infowindow2.open(map, marker2);

            });

            //moved 'SelectList' up toward top!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

            // End code for Marker 2
            // Start of Marker3 (Yellow - marker color)
            var latLng3 = new google.maps.LatLng(44.021778, -96.052417);
            var contentString3 = '<div id="content">';
            var infowindow3 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: contentString3
            });

            var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng3,
                icon: src = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/ylw-circle.png',
                map: map,
                title: "Marker ..."
            });
            markers[11] = marker3;

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker3, 'click', function () {
                infowindow3.open(map, marker3);
            });

            // End for Marker 3
            // Start of Marker4 (Green - marker color)
            var latLng4 = new google.maps.LatLng(43.881690, -95.922869);
            var contentString4 = '<div id="content">';
            var infowindow4 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: contentString4
            });

            var marker4 = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng4,
                icon: src = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/grn-circle.png',
                map: map,
                title: "marker ..."
            });
            markers[12] = marker4;

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker4, 'click', function () {
                infowindow4.open(map, marker4);
            });

            var infowindow4 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: contentString4
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker4, 'click', function () {
                infowindow4.open(map, marker4);
            });
            // End code for Marker 3

        }

        function dropdownChanged()
        {
            var index = document.getElementById("myList3").value;
            var marker = markers[index];
            var position = marker.getPosition();
            map.setCenter(position);
        }

</script>
```

EDIT 2 **
Here is how you hook the select to dropdownChanged

```
<select id = "myList3" onchange="dropdownChanged();">
               <option value = "9">Marker 1</option>
               <option value = "10">Marker 2</option>
               <option value = "11">Marker 3</option>
               <option value = "12">Marker 4</option>
             </select>
```

**EDIT 1 ***
As per your comment below, if you want to update the position from the dropdown you can simply call a function directly from the dropdown panTo(x,y)

```
<script>
function panTo(x,y)
{
   var position = new google.maps.LatLng(x,y);
   map.setCenter(position);
} 
</script>
```

Comment: I need to have the markers in this page, (not in an external page). Will this work if I store them in the page? Basically this page will be populated with several markers however I need to add this event to all markers. Thank you

Comment: Can't I add some onChange code to pan to a location once the pulldown value is selected? Like <option value = "javascript:panto XX.XXXX, -XX.XXXX">Location 1</option> the XX.XXX coordinates would be the same as one of my markers??? thanks

Comment: Yes you can do that, but then you would be storing the data in two places, which is not ideal. Anyway, if you really want to do that, I updated my answer of how to do that way.

Comment: Thank you I will try that. How does that link the function to my "myList1"?

Comment: Forgive me for being a novice, but what you wrote @albattran doesn't make sense, I understand the function but how does that get linked to my drop down list? Would I need a function for each marker? Also would I use the markers X,Y for the panTo and position? Since my dropdown list is in HTML can't I use something like this: <option value = "10 panto XX.XXXX, -XX.XXXX">Location 1</option> I don't understand why this is so complicated. I am about to just give up and get a job mowing lawns...pls help!

Comment: No worries, we are here to help:) You put the coordinates in the options, then parse the values in your on change and pass that over. This is why I recommend the first solution I provided, much simpler. I will add the html code how to do solution1, may be that will help you

Comment: I tried this: <option value = "javascript:panTo(43.239316:-96.259241)">Location 1</option> is this correct?

Comment: No that won't work. you need to put <option value="43.239316:-96.259241" >Location 1</option> then your onchange function need to parse this by getting the select value... Again, you are doing it the long way, use the first solution suggested above

Comment: I can explain later why it needs to be 'the long way' If I redo this I will have more issues than when I started. I will try this above, or if easier can you give me your email and I will send my entire page. thanks

Comment: Last Try:  function dropdownChanged()
          {
var index = document.getElementById("myList1").value;
var marker = markers[index];
var position = marker.getPosition();
map.setCenter(position);
function panTo(x,y)
var position = new google.maps.LatLng(43.239316, -96.259241);
map.setCenter(position);
<h3><u>---------List title----------</u></h3>
<select id = "myList1" onchange="dropdownChanged"();>
<option value = "43.239316:-96.259241">Location 1</option>

Comment: Do I still use both function statements (dropdownChanged & panTo) I am almost there, I need help @albattran

Comment: No, you only need to use dropdownchanged, no need for panTo

Comment: Just copy the code I pasted above in your page, you will see that it magically works. You don't need to even modify it, I basically took your code, fixed it up and pasted it back above.

Comment: no problem. Please mark the question as answered so others can benefit

Comment: There are up down arrows besides answers at the top (if you like or dislike a certain answer) and there is a check mark under them if you think an answer is the correct one